# I am having trouble with a nested If Statement in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to formulate a nested If Statement in Excel with three qualifications:

```
if sales are <100--> "Low"
if sales are between 100 and 1000-->"Mid"
if sales are greater than 1000-->"High"
```

Here's what I have so far:
        =IF(C3<100,"Low"), if(AND(C3>100,C3=1000)), "Mid"), if(C3>1000),"High"))

but the formula doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?

Best,
Bryan McCormack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## IF Trouble

### Compare

- Here is your formula that doesn't work, and below it is the formula
  in your 'style' that would have worked, to see where you went wrong.

  `=IF(C3<100,"Low"),IF(AND(C3>100,C3=1000)),"Mid"),IF(C3>1000),"High"))`
  `=IF(C3<100,"Low",IF(AND(C3>100,C3<=1000),"Mid",IF(C3>1000,"High","")))`

### Improve

- You can shorten the formula to the following:

  `=IF(C3<100,"Low",IF(C3<=1000,"Mid","High"))`
- You can add a check if there is a number in the cell:

  `=IF(ISNUMBER(C3),IF(C3<100,"Low",IF(C3<=1000,"Mid","High")),"")`

### Issues (Whole Numbers Only)

**Most of the following is incorrect for decimal numbers.**

- What is this formula doing?
  `=IF(C3<100,"Low",IF(C3<=1000,"Mid","High"))`

  1st Case: Value is less than 100 i.e. `..., 97, 98, 99.` .
  2nd Case: Value is between 99 and 1001 i.e. `100, 101, 102,..., 998, 999, 1000.` .
  *You could say Value is from 100 to 1000.*
  3rd Case: Value is greater than 1000 i.e. `1001, 1002, 1003,...` .
- Usually the same operators are used in such cases i.e. either:

  `=IF(C3<=100,"Low",IF(C3<=1000,"Mid","High"))`

  1st Case: Value is less than 101 i.e. `..., 98, 99, 100.`.
  2nd Case: Value is between 100 and 1001 i.e. `101, 102, 103,..., 998, 999, 1000.` .
  *You could say Value is from 101 to 1000.*
  3rd Case: Value is greater than 1000 i.e. `1001, 1002, 1003,...` .
- or:

  `=IF(C3<100,"Low",IF(C3<1000,"Mid","High"))`

  1st Case: Value is less than 100 i.e. `..., 97, 98, 99.` .
  2nd Case: Value is between 99 and 1000 i.e. `100, 101, 102,..., 997, 998, 999.` .
  *You could say Value is from 100 to 999.*
  3rd Case: Value is greater than 999 i.e. `1000, 1001, 1002,...` .

Notice the small differences in the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=if(C3<100, "Low", if(and(C3>=100,C3<=1000), "Mid","High"))
```

If it is not low and mid, then it's high

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your values in `Column C` are only numbers, this will do

```
=IF(C3<100, "Low", IF(C3>1000, "High", "Mid"))
```